# В минимальный срок или в минимальные сроки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно выбрать число в следующем сочетании: *выполнить задание* ***в минимальный срок*** или ***в минимальные сроки***?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел около сотни цитат в приличных изданиях (по гугло-книгам) и не смог заметить никакой разницы в употреблении. Создаётся впечатление, что для какого-то конкретного однократного действия чаще используется единственное число, а для протяжённого во времени на годы или десятилетия — множественное. Но и это в обоих случаях не всегда так.

Answer (score 1):

НКРЯ (http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2+%EC%E8%ED%E8%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9+%F1%F0%EE%EA) отмечены примеры множественного употребления в три раза превосходящие единственное. Какой либо логики вариативности обнаружить не удалось. Предположу — это дело не только вкуса, но и принципа: знающий цену времени и уважающий краткость изложения непременно остановится на *минимальном сроке* (примерно, как предпочтёт *потребует много сил* форме *потребует большого количества сил*).

Comment: Может быть,  имеет значение деление сложной работы на этапы. Например, строительство дома надо  закончить в минимальные сроки, а корабль привести в боевую готовность в минимальный срок.

Comment: Это разумно, т.е. множественность операций в сроках отражать. Так ведь действительность (все цитаты) это опровергает: всё запущено у них, всё украдено до нас.

Answer (score 1):

Мое предположение: употребление множественного числа подразумевает некоторую  неоднозначность. То ли сроков несколько (например, поэтапная сдача объекта), то ли срок окончания еще не известен, он может варьироваться в зависимости от обстоятельств (сколько вариантов, столько и сроков), но при любом развитии событий затраченное время должен быть сокращено до минимума.